# Unable to link Instagram (business) account to Facebook page

Tags: facebook, instagram

I have an Instagram account and a corresponding Facebook page. For historic reasons they are not linked, but I want them to be now. This is where I fail.

On the instagram App I was able to add the FB page to "Settings > Accounts > Linked Accounts > Facebook > [Page Name]", so new posts can be automatically posted to FB.

However, when follow the [official instructions to set the linked page](https://help.instagram.com/570895513091465?helpref=uf_permalink), i.e., I go to "Edit Profile > Profile > Page" or "Profile Tab >  ...  > Open Facebook" it does not allow me to chose a page, but instead only offers me to **Create A New Facebook Page**, which I clearly don't  want.

Background:

- I am the admin of the Facebook Page in question
- I also have added the Facebook account as well as the Instagram account in "Facebook Business Manager", where it oddly tells me for the Instagram account "This Instagram account is shared with other businesses."

Any suggestions on how to fix it, or simple reports on what you see when you go to "Edit Profile > Profile > Page" on a Instagram Business Account would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Downvoters, could you explain what I could have done better?

Answer (score 0):

Unlinking the account, switching pack to private, then switching back to business helped me solve this problem.

I still get the weird "This Instagram account is shared with other businesses" and lost all my past "Ad insights", but everything else seems to working fine